# Outlook 365 REST API endpoint Validity

Tags: outlook-restapi

In our code we are using the below REST API Endpoint https://outlook.office365.com/api/{version}/{user_context}

There was a mention in this link(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/use-outlook-rest-api) that the above REST API Endpoint will work for a while and that we will need to change to the new REST API. Please can you confirm the until when https://outlook.office365.com/api/{version}/{user_context} URL will be valid.

Thank you

Comment: This is more relevant for the Microsoft Support

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific date to share. Is there some reason you cannot switch to the `https://outlook.office.com` endpoint immediately? The API is exactly the same, so it should be a simple matter to change.